# Is it possible to integrate a react app in Salesforce Health Cloud using a lightning component?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, simple-salesforce

I'm new to salesforce and currently I only have a salesforce free account to do some tests and explore the CRM but I have a client that is thinking about integrating a react app in Salesforce.

For that to happen (from what I research) I need to have a paid Salesforce account and do the integration using a lightning component. My question is, if the client wants to use Health Cloud instead, can I do the integration the same way?
From what I read it's possible but I didn't find any concrete examples since apparently that feature (in Health Cloud) is quite new.

Can someone with salesforce experience confirm that it is possible and if using a lighning component is the best approach?